# Can I render a dithered pixel moving gradient background for my website using css and js?

Tags: css, web, graphics, dithering

I'm reasonably new to coding with css and js so I don't know where to start but I'd like to create a moving gradient background for transitions or something. Is there a way to stylistically dither the gradient like the retro styles of "Obra Dinn"?

Like this

[image: 1]

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do it. Take a normal gradient and apply a dithering algorithm to it. This question is too broad for the site in its current form, though. We can help with a code attempt.